# Does NP-hard problems have to be decision problems? (What the fact please) (contradicting answers)

Tags: np-complete, np-hard, np, decision-problem, p-vs-np

Let me explain my trouble by another example.

[The wiki page](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_problem) says that

> Lattice problems are an example of NP-hard problems

However, by clicking [NP-hard](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-hardness), i find this definition

> A decision problem H is NP-hard when for every problem L in NP, there is a polynomial-time many-one reduction from L to H.

What the fact?
Lattice problems are not decision problems.

**Edit after two answers:**
I think the two answers below have contradicting definitions:

> 1-)An optimization problem is NP-hard if it is as hard as NP-hard decision problems.

> 2-) An optimization problem is NP-hard if its decision version is
> NP-hard.

Which one is the real definition.

Comment: We also have a very well-regarded [reference question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/9556/what-is-the-definition-of-p-np-np-complete-and-np-hard) on these terms.

Comment: Are you aware that is a link to a "pirated" copy of a copyrighted book?  Please don't post links to "pirated" content.  Instead, cite the book and give a proper reference: title, authors, chapter, section, page number, etc.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the definition of P, NP, NP-complete and NP-hard?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/9556/what-is-the-definition-of-p-np-np-complete-and-np-hard)

Comment: @Evil I am aware of that link but i cant find any answer from that link.

Answer (score 3):

In complexity theory, we often concentrate on decision problems. "Officially," NP-hardness is a category of decision problems — only a decision problem can be (or not be) NP-hard.

However, it is also common to use NP-hardness when referring to *optimization* problems. An optimization problem is NP-hard if its decision version is NP-hard.

In more advanced complexity theory, NP-hardness is used in a less precise way. For example, [this paper](https://eccc.weizmann.ac.il/report/2000/073/download)
"give[s] a new proof showing that it is NP-hard to color a 3-colorable graph using just four colors". They also prove that it is NP-hard to distinguish graphs of type A from graphs of type B (see their Theorem 3). What they really mean, in the former case, is that for any problem $L$ in NP there exists a polynomial time reduction $f$, outputting a graph, such that if $x \in L$ then $f(x)$ is 3-colorable, and if $x \notin L$ then $f(x)$ is not 4-colorable.

Comment: I think these two definitions contradicts:

1-)An optimization problem is NP-hard if it is more difficult than any problem in NP
2-) An optimization problem is NP-hard if its decision version is NP-hard.

Which one is the real definition.

Comment: The first one isn’t really a definition. What does it mean to be more difficult than any problem in NP?

Comment: Could you please give any reference?

Comment: You’ll have to trust me.

Comment: Yes, I trust you but all the people have to trust you. Since people use different definitions, I cant understand what they mean by NP-hard

Comment: There’s no “book of definitions” which, by fiat, contains all the correct definitions, if that’s what you’re looking for. The definition of NP-hardness for decision problems is not problematic, I assume (though sometimes one uses different notions of reduction; that will always be made explicit). NP-hardness of other types of problems is a more informal notion, though it can be formalized. Perhaps Arora and Barak’s textbook contains such a definition (probably not overly formal).

Answer (score 1):

Now that you have edited your post, your question is more clear ('cause let's be honest, it was very confusing before the modifications…)

By definition, problems in $NP$ are decision problems. However, $NP$-hard problems are not necessarily in $NP$ and even not necessarily decision problems.

Let's make an example of this. Consider the following decision problem:

Clique – Input: a graph $G$ and an integer $k$; Question: is there a subgraph of $G$ that is a clique of size $k$?

It is well known that Clique is a decision problem in $NP$ (and even $NP$-complete). Consider now the following optimization problem:

max-Clique – Input: a graphe $G$; Maximize: the size a subgraph $H$ of $G$; Conditions: $H$ is a clique.

Now we will prove that max-Clique is $NP$-hard, despite not being a decision problem. Indeed, if you know how to solve max-Clique, then given a graph $G$ and an integer $k$, you can solve Clique$(G, k)$ by running max-Clique$(G)$ and verifying if the result is greater than $k$ or not. This is done in an additionnal polynomial time. That proves that Clique $\leq_m^p$ max-Clique. Since Clique is $NP$-complete, we conclude that max-Clique is $NP$-hard.

Comment: Then, what the wiki page mean here:  "Lattice problems are an example of NP-hard problems

Comment: It roughly means "more difficult than any problem in $NP$".

Comment: Thanks. You really answered my question. Then the all definitions starting "the decision problem is NP-hard if ..."  are wrong.

Comment: Another question: Can you verify your answer by references. Is there a standart reference for this topic.

Comment: Not necessarily: you can chose to talk about $NP$-hardness only for decision problems. What would be wrong would be "we define a $NP$-hard problem as a decision problem verifying…"

Comment: You can find references on wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-hardness#Consequences https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_packing#Special_cases