# Is Knapsack-optimization problem NP-hard while Knapsack-search problem NP-complete?

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete, np, knapsack-problems

I am learning Computational Complexity.

Is Knapsack-optimization problem (find an arrangement to maximize the value) known to be NP-hard, while Knapsack-search problem (find an arrangement so that value >= a number) known to be NP-complete?

For the Knapsack-search problem to be NP-complete, should I have assumed that all weight, value are integer?

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/9556/755, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_problem

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/137136/does-np-hard-problems-have-to-be-decision-problems-what-the-fact-please-cont/